# Prevent user from clicking html.routelink in MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using a routelink and setting parameters based on what I get from my viewModel. Is there a way to prevent the user from even being able to click the link?

Comment: Why do you put a link into a web page when you don't want the users to click it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent a user from clicking an hyperlink once it is on the page.Even there is, it doesn't make any sense. Maybe what you were trying to do was, render the link in view only on some conditions like this:

```
<% if(someCondition)
{
Html.RouteLink(
            item.Head,
            "Details",
            new
            {
              controller = "Article",
              action = "Details",
              id = item.ID
            });
}
%>
```